# Android Annotation - Null pointer Exception on methode init of the generated class

Tags: android, android-annotations

I just start a new Android project, with the Android Annotation Library.
[Android Annotation](http://androidannotations.org/)

I've got two Activity : StartScreen who contains a button "information" who start a seconde Activity InfoActivity. Both are annotated.

The first one work very well, but when I clicked on the "Information" button, I've got a `NullPointerException` on the `public static class IntentBuilder_` of the generated class : 'InfoActivity_'

Here is the error trace :

```
04-16 09:32:29.329: E/AndroidRuntime(561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3122)
at com.cinapp.dombox.tablet.activity.InfoActivity_$IntentBuilder_.<init>(InfoActivity_.java:63)
at com.cinapp.dombox.tablet.activity.InfoActivity_.intent(InfoActivity_.java:53)
at com.cinapp.dombox.tablet.activity.StartScreen.buttonInformation(StartScreen.java:24)
at com.cinapp.dombox.tablet.activity.StartScreen_$1.onClick(StartScreen_.java:44)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the `InfoActivity` more or less empty :

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_info)
public class InfoActivity extends Activity {

}
```

Here is the `InfoActivity_` :

```
public final class InfoActivity_
extends InfoActivity
{


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    init_(savedInstanceState);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_info);
}

private void init_(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

private void afterSetContentView_() {
}

@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    afterSetContentView_();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view, LayoutParams params) {
    super.setContentView(view, params);
    afterSetContentView_();
}

@Override
public void setContentView(View view) {
    super.setContentView(view);
    afterSetContentView_();
}

public static InfoActivity_.IntentBuilder_ intent(Context context) {
    return new InfoActivity_.IntentBuilder_(context);
}

public static class IntentBuilder_ {

    private Context context_;
    private final Intent intent_;

    public IntentBuilder_(Context context) {
        context_ = context;
        intent_ = new Intent(context, InfoActivity_.class);
    }

    public Intent get() {
        return intent_;
    }

    public InfoActivity_.IntentBuilder_ flags(int flags) {
        intent_.setFlags(flags);
        return this;
    }

    public void start() {
        context_.startActivity(intent_);
    }

    public void startForResult(int requestCode) {
        if (context_ instanceof Activity) {
            ((Activity) context_).startActivityForResult(intent_, requestCode);
        } else {
            context_.startActivity(intent_);
        }
    }

}

}
```

And finally here is the `Android Manifest``

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exemple.application"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.StartScreen_"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_screen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.InfoActivity_"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_info" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.exemple.application.activity.StartScreen_" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**It is suppose to be very easy but I guess missed something**

Comment: a bit off topic, but where does this `_` style for names come from? I see more and more people using this confusing name style...

Comment: the `_` at the end the class name, is used to refer to the generated Class. It a convention used by the Android Annotation library see : http://androidannotations.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you start you're second activity ?

According to the stacktrace, it seems that the context in the Intent is null, so I think you made your call like this `InfoActivity_.intent(null).start()`

When you create a new activity you need to pass a context to it, so in the StartScreenActivity you should do something like this : `InfoActivity_.intent(this).start()`

Comment: Whao, I feel so stupid. I was lanching the Activity like that : `  InfoActivity_.intent(context).start();` **BUT** I've never init `context`

Comment: what is the best "Android Annotation"'s way to init a context parameter ? I've done that : ` @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  context = this;
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 }`

Comment: If you're in an Activity just use `this`. An Activity IS a Context. If you're in in Bean you can use the [@RootContext annotation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-custom-classes)